# How does one create a "at least n" constraint?

Tags: python, algorithm, constraints, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am new to constraint programming and try to figure out how to do a "at least n" constraint.

For example I have int variables x, y and z all within a range of 0 to 5.

Now I want all solutions in which at least 2 of the variables are between 2 and 3.

So something like a "sum of given conditions >= 2"

How would I do this in python and ideally with Google's OR-Tools?

Thanks

Comment: You can use *reified* constraints for that: https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem - is there a more scalable version? I need to ramp this up to find solutions where the combination of 6 variables must fit in a table of 10 slots. As an example, I need to schedule 6 teachers 8 hour shifts, each with 30 min break, and make sure that there are at least 4 teachers in the room between 8am and 12pm and at least 5 teachers in the room between 12pm and 6pm.

Comment: @Christine I don't see the scalability problem here.A 1000 var / 10000 slot problem while using pure SAT-solving would scare me. But a (lazy) CP-SAT Hybrid with those numbers (although it's hard to foresee the behaviour with that small ranges)... well... try it first. Of course the rest of the model is equally important and if there is not much more, it's questionable if CP-SAT should be preferred to MIP-approaches imho.

Comment: First, I would not use integer variables at all. Just Boolean variables. Second, on this kind of problems, my experience is that CP-SAT is better than CBC/SCIP and worse than Gurobi/CPLEX.

Answer (score 3):

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
import collections


class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self, variables):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__variables = variables
        self.__num_vars = len(variables)
        self.__num_values = len(variables[0])
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.__solution_count += 1
        for var in range(self.__num_vars):
            for value in range(self.__num_values):
                if self.BooleanValue(self.__variables[var][value]):
                    print('var[%i]=%i' % (var, value), end=' ')
                    break
        print()

    def solution_count(self):
        return self.__solution_count


num_vars = 3
max_values = 5

model = cp_model.CpModel()
vars = collections.defaultdict(list)

for var in range(num_vars):
    for value in range(max_values + 1):
        vars[var].append(model.NewBoolVar('x_%i_%i' % (var, value)))

# Exactly one value per variable
for var in range(num_vars):
    model.Add(sum(vars[var]) == 1)

# At least 2 between 2 and 3
model.Add(sum(vars[var][2] for var in range(num_vars)) +
          sum(vars[var][3] for var in range(num_vars)) >= 2)

# Enumerate all solutions
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solution_printer = SolutionPrinter(vars)
status = solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)

print('Status = %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
print('Number of solutions found: %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())
```

outputs

```
var[0]=3      var[1]=2      var[2]=0 
var[0]=3      var[1]=2      var[2]=5 
var[0]=3      var[1]=2      var[2]=4 
var[0]=3      var[1]=2      var[2]=1 
var[0]=3      var[1]=2      var[2]=3 
var[0]=3      var[1]=0      var[2]=3 
var[0]=3      var[1]=1      var[2]=3 
var[0]=3      var[1]=5      var[2]=3 
var[0]=3      var[1]=4      var[2]=3 
var[0]=3      var[1]=4      var[2]=2 
var[0]=3      var[1]=0      var[2]=2 
var[0]=3      var[1]=1      var[2]=2 
var[0]=3      var[1]=2      var[2]=2 
var[0]=3      var[1]=5      var[2]=2 
var[0]=3      var[1]=3      var[2]=2 
var[0]=3      var[1]=3      var[2]=4 
var[0]=3      var[1]=3      var[2]=5 
var[0]=3      var[1]=3      var[2]=1 
var[0]=3      var[1]=3      var[2]=0 
var[0]=3      var[1]=3      var[2]=3 
var[0]=5      var[1]=3      var[2]=3 
var[0]=1      var[1]=3      var[2]=3 
var[0]=4      var[1]=3      var[2]=3 
var[0]=2      var[1]=3      var[2]=3 
var[0]=0      var[1]=3      var[2]=3 
var[0]=2      var[1]=3      var[2]=0 
var[0]=2      var[1]=3      var[2]=5 
var[0]=2      var[1]=3      var[2]=4 
var[0]=2      var[1]=3      var[2]=1 
var[0]=2      var[1]=3      var[2]=2 
var[0]=5      var[1]=3      var[2]=2 
var[0]=1      var[1]=3      var[2]=2 
var[0]=4      var[1]=3      var[2]=2 
var[0]=0      var[1]=3      var[2]=2 
var[0]=0      var[1]=2      var[2]=2 
var[0]=5      var[1]=2      var[2]=2 
var[0]=4      var[1]=2      var[2]=2 
var[0]=1      var[1]=2      var[2]=2 
var[0]=2      var[1]=2      var[2]=2 
var[0]=2      var[1]=0      var[2]=2 
var[0]=2      var[1]=1      var[2]=2 
var[0]=2      var[1]=5      var[2]=2 
var[0]=2      var[1]=4      var[2]=2 
var[0]=2      var[1]=2      var[2]=1 
var[0]=2      var[1]=2      var[2]=0 
var[0]=2      var[1]=2      var[2]=5 
var[0]=2      var[1]=2      var[2]=4 
var[0]=2      var[1]=2      var[2]=3 
var[0]=2      var[1]=0      var[2]=3 
var[0]=2      var[1]=1      var[2]=3 
var[0]=5      var[1]=2      var[2]=3 
var[0]=4      var[1]=2      var[2]=3 
var[0]=1      var[1]=2      var[2]=3 
var[0]=2      var[1]=5      var[2]=3 
var[0]=2      var[1]=4      var[2]=3 
var[0]=0      var[1]=2      var[2]=3 
Status = OPTIMAL
Number of solutions found: 56
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have these conditions

```
x = 2.5
y = 4
z = 2.9
```

then you could build a list of values, and then apply `lambda`, `map` and `sum` to find things out. For example:

```
# Create the list of values
values = [x, y, z]

# Apply a lambda to each element of the list, checking if they
# are within [2,3]. This would return a boolean, so I am translating
# those to 1 and 0
ones_or_zeroes = map(lambda x: 1 if 2<=x<=3 else 0, values)

# Check condition of how many matched the condition:
condition = sum(ones_or_zeroes)
```

It can be of course compacted as:

```
if sum(map(lambda x: 1 if 2<=x<=3 else 0, values)) >= 2:
    # then at least 2 variables match the costraint
    pass
```